# Is it possible to reduce samples sent by node-exporter?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, prometheus, monitoring, prometheus-node-exporter

I have setup like below:

- On-prem k8s cluster with Managed Service for Prometheus and node_exporter deployed.
- GCP Monitoring to visualize node_exporter metrics.

GCP charges me $0.15 for every million samples.

I already filtered out metrics that I don't need. Only 3 of them left, which are:

1. `node_filesystem_avail_bytes`
2. `node_cpu_seconds_total`
3. `node_memory_MemTotal_bytes`

I also reduced metrics scraping from 30s to 60s.

Filesystem and memory metrics are negligible but `node_cpu_seconds_total` sends ~7 samples/s.

I'm wondering if it's possible to reduce this sampling?

I also don't fully understand the idea behind this. Why all samples between scraping period all pulled instead of pure value. I mean  this could be done by simple substraction s1-s0/<scrape_time>.

But probably I don't know something.

I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Do I understand correctly "`node_cpu_seconds_total` sends ~7 samples **per scrape**`? So you'd want to filter by label value?

Comment: I'm using Managed Prometheus with managed collection and this entails adding `matchOneOf` (**include**) filters to `operatorconfig/config`. You wrote that you've "filtered out metrics that I don't need". How did you do this? If you're using `operatorconfig/config`, you can **include** the above metrics and you can at the same time specify combinations of label values that you want (thereby eliminating those that you don't).

Comment: @DazWilkin metrics can be filter out with Relabeling https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/setup-managed#filter-metrics
7 samples per second not per scrape. You can watch this in monitoring diagnostics and billable samples ingested chart. Scraping is each 60 seconds, but if I understand correctly all data points (samples) between these 60s are pulled from node-exporter.

Comment: ok, finally I fond out why so many samples are ingested. I have 2 servers but node_exporter breaks each physical CPU to 24 CPUs ( Thread(s) per core: 2, Core(s) per socket: 12). What is more there are 8 modes (idle, iowait, irq.... etc). So 2x24x8=368. 368/60s is 7 samples per second.
So now the question is can I reduce it somehow? I need only idle mode. I assume that I can't change the way node_exporter gathering data for CPU and 2 core/12 threads have to be ingested seperately.

Comment: So, it appears you can't [exclude](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter#include--exclude-flags) CPU metrics collected by the Node Exporter

Comment: But, to you point, you can [filter exported metrics](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/setup-managed#filter-metrics) through the `*PodMonitoring`. Have you tried that?

Comment: I sent you the same link. I didn't say I want to filter out CPU metrics. I need this metric...

Comment: Yes, understood. But you said you only need idle mode key-values and so you need to filter the metric by it's name (which is one label `__name__`) and whatever value holds the mode so that you only get idle mode. So you wanna `drop` anything that's e.g. `{__name__="node_cpu_seconds_total",mode!="idle"}` and convert that to a relabel config.